# ¿Está esté código Correcto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Saludos,

Estoy haciendo un formulario de cotización y me pregunto si este código es correcto, **funciona normal** pero eso es solo para motocicletas, deberé crear el mismo para Automóviles, Camperos, Buses y Tractocamiones, entonces copio y pego este mismo código ajustando los valores o cómo se puede mejorar?

Cotiza.cs

```
 String getChainVar =
            this.listCotSoatClaseVehiculo.SelectedValue +
            this.listCotSoatCilindraje.SelectedValue +
            //this.listCotSoatTonelaje.SelectedValue +
            //this.listCotSoatPasajeros.SelectedValue +
            modelo2007
            ;
        String TotalSoatMotos = "";

        if (getChainVar == "110" | getChainVar == "111")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "306.260";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "120" | getChainVar == "121")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "410.660";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "130" | getChainVar == "131")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "463.010";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "140" | getChainVar == "141")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "$63.010";
        }


        this.pnlTotalCotizacionSoat.Visible = true;
        this.lblCotSoatTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalSoatMotos);
```

[image: Formulario de prueba]

Lo que hice fué: recoger los valores de los Inputs en una string, y segun el código que recogí de esa string le asigné un valor con If.

** Nota: A lo mejor sea básico, pero yo estoy aprendiendo ASP.NET empíricamente no soy universitario así que hago lo que puedo XD.**

Comment: a que te refieres con "está correcto" ¿qué problema tienes con el código? recuerda que en programación, siempre hay muchas maneras de hacer una misma cosa, así que, lo que a ti te funcione, tal vez otra persona lo haga de manera distinta a ti.

Comment: Claro, buena aclaración, no hay error funciona pero me refiero a que si es la mejor manera de hacerlo, o que manera es más recomendable? Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: el código es correcto para lo que quieres no veo una mejor manera para algo tan sencillo. lo que te hace falta es un mensaje de error si es menor a 110 y otro error si es mayor de 141. entre las buenas practica tambien esta el control de posibles errores humanos y de software.

Comment: a lo mejor, y muy a mi modo, utilizaría un switch en vez de esos if, pero funciona y está claro, sólo al final agrega un else para codificar una exepción, o en su caso, 2 if más para el caso que sea menor a 110 o mayor a 141, como dice @franciscoNúñez

Comment: bueno el uso de un switch o u if para algo tan simple es cuestionable ya que no proporcionara una mejora en tiempo de respuesta al usuario... tal vez para el que programe si, tendríamos que saber si el busca mejorar la experiencia de usuario o su habilidad como programador..

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez sé que no mejora el código, por algo dije "a mi modo", y es como le expliqué al principio, cada quien tiene su manera de hacer las cosas

Comment: Trate con `switch` pero no logré hacerlo funcionar, ¿cómo sería eso? y para el `else`, cada que lo agrego simplemente de deja de calcular y no me arroja nada, no se porque. T_T

Comment: a lo mejor este enlace te ayuda a entender el switch: http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=483:switch-en-java-condicional-de-seleccion-diagrama-de-flujo-y-ejemplo-de-aplicacion-ejercicio-cu00637b&catid=68&Itemid=188

Comment: respecto al else, puedes hacer que en el bloque de código de muestre algún mensaje de error, o depurar para ver que está haciendo, intenta poniendo un if hasta arriba del todo para comparar que el valor no sea menor a 110, y un if al final para comparar que el valor no sea mayor a 141

Comment: lo cierto es que al caer en cuenta veo que usas comparaciones de texto, y creo que seria mejor manejarlo como numero o float... en tal caso seria para manejar las condiciones de errores(error si es menor a 110 y otro error si es mayor de 141).

Comment: Listo muchachos muchas gracias, seguiré experimentando.

Comment: Creo que el código necesita una refactorización grande, porque es un código muy específico.Como tu dices, que pasa cuando seleccionen un Automóvil? que pasa si a lo largo del tiempo existen mas valores de `getChainVar` además de los que ya tienes? En todos esos casos, un pequeño cambio te supondría tener que modificar código en muchos sitios. Explicarte todo queda un poco fuera del ambito del sitio, pero te aconsejaría usar una clase base y heredar de ella, y usar por ejemplo un diccionario para los valores posibles de `getChainVar` con su correspondiente valor.

Comment: el uso OR en C# es || Https://mva.microsoft.com aquí tienes grandes cursos de tecnologías Microsoft y tecnologías no-Microsoft. Dictados por personas altamente calificadas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

1. Utilizar las dobles pipes: || esto representa el operador OR en C# y en muchos otros lenguajes de programación también.
2. Convertir un string a otro string carece de sentido, mejor pásalo de frente

.

```
String getChainVar =
            this.listCotSoatClaseVehiculo.SelectedValue +
            this.listCotSoatCilindraje.SelectedValue +
            //this.listCotSoatTonelaje.SelectedValue +
            //this.listCotSoatPasajeros.SelectedValue +
            modelo2007
            ;
        String TotalSoatMotos = "";

        if (getChainVar == "110" || getChainVar == "111")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "306.260";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "120" || getChainVar == "121")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "410.660";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "130" || getChainVar == "131")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "463.010";
        }
        if (getChainVar == "140" || getChainVar == "141")
        {
            TotalSoatMotos = "63.010";
        }    

        this.pnlTotalCotizacionSoat.Visible = true;
        this.lblCotSoatTotal.Text = TotalSoatMotos;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones, ya decía yo que algo no me parecía correcto, aunque con el || pipe o | funciona igual, se me hace algo raro y convertir el string es que me ponía error de conversión, pero ya lo resolví.